# Batch commands to swap text from file

Tags: windows, batch-file, command

**This is the input file:-**

```
Hello,1-23456
How are you,2-34567
.
.
.
```

**I want output:-**

```
1-23456,Hello
2-34567,How are you
.
.
.
```

Please help me to create a batch file for this.

I have tried this

```
@echo off &setlocal

set "textfile=inputchq.csv"
set "newfile=output.txt"

(for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%i in (%textfile%) do set srno=%%a&set comments=%%b (
    set "line=%%i"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "line=%comments%,%srno%"
    echo(!line!
    endlocal
))>>"%newfile%"
```

But i am not getting the desired output

Comment: What have you tried? Please attempt to solve your own questions before asking them here, and add what you have come up with to your question.

Comment: I have attempted to this problem, please take a look and help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off &setlocal

set "textfile=inputchq.csv"
set "newfile=output.txt"

(for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%a in (%textfile%) do (
    echo %%b,%%a"
))>>"%newfile%"
```

Edit to match additional requirement from comment:

you need delayed expansion and to escape the special character "|"

```
@echo off 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "textfile=inputchq.csv"
set "newfile=output.txt"

(for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%a in (%textfile%) do (
    set "line=%%b,%%a"
    echo !line:^|=.!
))>>%newfile%
```

Comment: In this same solution i want to replace all "|" with "." where can i add in this loop.Please help.